# How do I apply an svg fill effect to a div class?

Tags: html, css, svg, fill

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3kvfq7z/1/)

**HTML**

```
<body onLoad="initialize()">
<svg>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="wood" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="400" height="400">
            <image xlink:href="http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/purty_wood.png" width="400" height="400" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <text y="1.2em">Sample</text>
</svg>

<div id="container">
    <div id="minute"></div>
    <div id="hour"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 320px;
height: 570px;
font-family: Default;}
svg {
width: 6em;
height: 1.5em;
font: 900 500%/1.2'Arial Black', sans-serif;
}
text {
fill: url(#wood);
text-shadow:  0px -2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.9), 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.9);
}
#container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
}

#minute {
fill: url(#wood);
position: Absolute;
right: 10px;
font-family:"Arial";
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 40px;
text-align: right;
text-shadow:  0px -2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.9), 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.9);
}
#hour {
fill: url(#wood);
position: Absolute;
right: 55px;
font-family:"Arial";
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 68px;
text-align: right;
text-shadow:  0px -2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.9), 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.9);
}
```

Sorry if my question is poorly worded, been a while since I've done this so a lot of the terminology escapes me (probably also the reason I haven't found the answer elsewhere.) I want to apply the wood image (seen on the sample text on the left) to the text that makes up the clock on the right. Can svg only be applied to text defined in the html or is it possible to apply it to dynamic(?) text like the clock?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need SVG for this.  Just set your image directly as a background for your divs.

```
#minute {
    background: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/purty_wood.png);
}
```

**Update:**

You cannot apply SVG patterns to HTML text, but you can apply it SVG `<text>` elements.

```
<text id="container" x="20" y="250">
    <tspan id="hour"></tspan>
    <tspan id="minute" dy="-0.5em"></tspan>
</text>
```

[Demo fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/u3kvfq7z/3/)

Comment: That seems to just set the background of the entire div rather than the text within it. Also, I believe the background property appears beneath the shadow so would not be visible. Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: Sorry.  I was going by your question title, not the different problem at the bottom of your question.  The answer is you can't apply an SVG pattern (or any SVG fill) to HTML text elements.

Comment: So is what I want to achieve (the clock text with an image overlay and a shadow) just completely impossible or is there another area I can look into? You've no need to be sorry; I apologise for my mistake.

Comment: Not impossible.  You can apply a pattern to arbitrary text if the text is part of the SVG (ie SVG `<text>` elements).  Or you could do patterned text in the HTML if you use pre-prepared patterned character images.